# Issue with NavCtrl Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I will do my best to explain this issue.

I have a dropdown on my login page that sets NgModel Location which is part of the URL it does a get request from. So for instance http.get(www. + location + .com)

the first time I set the NGModel from the select and on click make the request the request works fine and goes to the next page and displays the data it returned.

When I use the back button that was built in to the default side menu or even this.navctrl.push(loginpage) and then select something else from the dropdown click and make the httprequest the NGModel is still set to what was selected the first time.

So for instance on the first request I set the NGModel in dropdown to Illinois.
http.get(www.Illinois.com)

and then use built in navctrl back button or use the this.navtrl.push(loginpage)

this time I select California from the dropdown. I still get
http.get(www.Illinois.com)

Any ideas what the issue could be here?

A little background of how I'm setting location on the LoginPage

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
    <img style="display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 25%;" src="assets/imgs/DotFoodsLogo.jpg">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input style="text-align: right" [(ngModel)]="employeeNumber" (change)="getTasks(employeeNumber, location)" type="number"
        value="" item-right></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Location</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="location" (ngModelChange)="getTasks(employeeNumber, location)" interface="popover">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let databasename of locations">{{databasename.DatabaseName}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item *ngIf="employeeNumber != null && location != null">
      <ion-label>Task</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="task" interface="popover">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let task of tasks">{{task.TaskDisplay}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-buttons text-center *ngIf="employeeNumber != null && location != null && task != null">

      <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="attemptLogin(employeeNumber, location)">
        Log in
      </button>

  </ion-buttons>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: real quick: so your uses shorthand for ngModel - [(ngModel)] - which is equivalent to something like: <ion-select [ngModel]="var" (ngModelChange)="var = $event">. So I am not saying this is why your code doesn't work, but definitely something not in line with how it should be;)

Answer (score 0):

I can see few things that can explain the behaviour that you are seeing.

1- Making `this.navtrl.push(loginpage)` will add a new instance of loginPage. as result, you endup having both loginPages listening to the same event.

Instead, use `this.navCtrl.pop();` or `this.navCtrl.setRoot(loginpage);`

2- location and employeeNumber are instance properties, so you don't need to include them in your getTasks(employeeNumber, location).

Instead, do something like this :

```
getTasks(){
   //access location and employeeNumber like so
   console.log(this.location);
   console.log(this.employeeNumber );
   If you see this console printing twice, it means you have duplicate pages.
}
```

3- use console.log(this.location) in your ngOnInit() which should trigger whenever you come back to the page or create a new instance. It will also help you understand what's happening.

Comment: I can check that out and maybe it's related... the way this actually works is that the location is set on the login page and then sent to the next page using this.navctrl.push(nextPage, location)... it works the first time and then when I log in the next time and push back to the nextPage is where the location is still the same as it was set the first time

Comment: try (ionChange)="getTasks(employeeNumber, location)" instead of (change)="getTasks(employeeNumber, location)"